# HINT: There is a column named "title" in table "wenzhang", but it cannot be referenced from this part of the query

Tags: python, postgresql, psycopg2

I was trying to insert content from spyder. I connected to the database successfully. And then the error happened.

```
connet = psycopg2.connect(database="sample", 
user="users",password="123456",host="localhost",port="5432")

cursor = connet.cursor()

def downloadPage(url):
    content=''
    response = requests.get(url)
    response.encoding = 'UTF-8'
    bs = BeautifulSoup(response.text,'lxml')
    title = bs.find('h1').text
    div = bs.find('div',attrs={'class':'neirong'})
    ps = div.findAll('p')

    for p in ps:
        content+=p.text+'\n'
    return title,content

for url in urls:
    title,content = downloadPage(url)
    print(title)
    sql = "insert into wenzhang(title,conten) values(title,content)";
    cursor.execute(sql)
```

Error:

```
psycopg2.errors.UndefinedColumn: column "title" does not exist
LINE 1: insert into wenzhang(title,conten) values(title,content)
                                                  ^
```

HINT:  There is a column named "title" in table "wenzhang", but it cannot be referenced from this part of the query.

Comment: Can you elaborate on the values you're trying to insert? Where are they defined?

Comment: sql = "insert into wenzhang(title,conten) values(%s,%s)".format(title,conten). use this way to insert your variables into the query, I feel the error is because of the values not because of column names.

Comment: @Murali Don't do that. That's a recipe for SQL injection.

Comment: @melpomene yeah Sorry my bad, he can pass that to execute function as you said

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that the database knows nothing about your Python program and its variables. You're telling it to run the code

```
insert into wenzhang(title,content) values(title,content)
```

so it thinks both `title` and `content` are columns of some table.

To [pass variables to SQL queries](http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/usage.html#passing-parameters-to-sql-queries), you can do:

```
cursor.execute("insert into wenzhang(title,content) values(%s, %s)", (title,content))
```

I.e. use `%s` where you want to insert a Python value in the SQL query, and pass a list of Python values as a second argument.

Answer (score 1):

Currently, your value clause just has `title` and `content` as barewords, which Postgres interprets as columns names, explaining the error you're getting.

What you need to do is bind the `title` and `content` variables you have using the second argument of the `execute` method:

```
sql = "insert into wenzhang (title, conten) values (%s, %s)";
cursor.execute(sql, (title, content))
```